# Changes package, struck-through text rendering in blue

Tags: hyperref, changes

I am working on updating a complex document, and we need to clearly indicate all text that has been added or removed. I am using the changes package, like this:

```
\usepackage[addedmarkup=bf, deletedmarkup=sout]{changes}
```

We need the changes to be visible in greyscale, since we will be making printed copies of that sort.

For some reason, struck-through text is rendering in blue. Maybe it's an incompatibility with hyperref? In any event, a fix would be very much appreciated.

The full files are at:

http://www.sindark.com/350/fossil-fuel-divest-new-SE-2015-04-06.pdf
(.tex and .bib in the same location)

There is some struck-out text on the second page of the PDF.

Thanks!

Milan

---

Added: Here is something like a MWE, but for some reason it makes both added and struck-out text blue, unlike my big document which only does it for struck-out text:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[addedmarkup=bf, deletedmarkup=sout]{changes}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=navy]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here is some normal text

\added{Here is some added text}

\replaced{Old and broken}{New and shiny}

\end{document}
```

---

Added:

I tried adding:

```
\usepackage{soul}
```

to the preamble and:

```
\setstcolor{black}
```

to the main document, but struck-out text still appears blue.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Should the MWE include the entire preamble for the document, and then a bit of text that shows the problem?

Comment: The relevant packages and some text, you could use `\usepackage{blindtext}` and `\blindtext` in the document body to prevent tedious typing/copying of text

Comment: I think, you should use `\definechangesauthor` to set an id and the color explicitly. The `changes.sty` file explictly defines an `empty` author and all changes to be set in blue color

Comment: See my possible solution

Answer (score 2):

`changes` defines the `\definechangesauthor` command which has some options, e.g. `color` for choosing the text color and as mandatory argument a author name, say `foo`.

However this command defines counters which names are created from the author name, such as `Changes@AddCountfoo` etc. which are automatically incremented.

In `changes.sty` the command `\definechangesauthor[color=blue]{\@empty}`, defining an `empty` author with default blue markup.

A second call, with, say `color=gray` will fail, since the relevant counters are defined already. One way to circumvent this is to `\undef` the counter names being already defined.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[addedmarkup=bf, deletedmarkup=sout]{changes}

\makeatletter
\undef\c@Changes@DeleteCount%
\undef\c@Changes@AddCount%
\undef\c@Changes@ReplaceCount%
\definechangesauthor[color={gray}]{\@empty}
\makeatother



\usepackage[colorlinks=false,allcolors=navy]{hyperref}



\begin{document}

Here is some normal text

\added{Here is some added text}

\replaced{Old and broken}{New and shiny}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could using the nocolor markup option solve your problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[markup=nocolor, addedmarkup=bf]{changes}
\begin{document}

  Text

  \added{added}

  \deleted{deleted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The nocolor option makes added text underlined, whereas we want it to be bold.

Comment: Added text appears underlined if I try with the `nocolor` option. That's not the only option you're using, is it? Try `\usepackage[markup=nocolor,addedmarkup=bf,deletedmarkup=sout]{changes}`