# Patching/Preventing effective code in a package

Tags: macros, package-writing

Consider a command being defined in a package (or used from another package), say `\somethingstupid` and being used before `\endinput` within the package, doing some non-typesetting setup (coloring, setting lengths, counters etc. or even defining other commands...).

Sometimes this code is annoying and should not be used at all.

Is there a way to `patch` the package (not only the command) to prevent this **effective** code?

*Of course the 'annoying' part of the command can be patched but this can be complicated.*

Here is a MWE

**dummypackage.sty**

```
\ProvidesPackage{dummypackage}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\somethingstupid}[1]{%
%%% A lot of non-typesetting code before
\color{#1}   % 'stupid' too
%%% A lot of non-typesetting code after
}

%%% Other stuff

\somethingstupid{blue} % Should not be here for some reasons 

%%% Other stuff


\endinput
```

And some driver `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dummypackage}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, not in a general way. You could patch `\newcommand` to trap the offending command(s) (very fragile, of course), but there are too many possible variants: some command can even not being explicitly defined.

Comment: @egreg: I feared this :-(

Comment: Knowing what action `\somethingstupid` does, you can undo it as soon as the package is loaded. Or try patching `\@begindocumenthook` if the code is delayed (difficult, though).

Comment: Could you patch `\somethingstupid` to save a copy of itself and then redefine itself to innocuous behavior.  And then, add an `\AtBeginDocument` macro to reinstate the original definition?

Comment: @egreg: The reason why I asked is the answer I gave to this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237134/changes-package-struck-through-text-rendering-in-blue (which is basically what you proposed: Redefining/reusing/redoing code)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: See my comment to egreg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This puts

```
Ignoring \somethingstupid
```

in the log and doesn't execute the package definition of `\somethingstupid`

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zsomethingstupid{\somethingstupid}
\let\znewcommand\newcommand
\def\newcommand#1{%
\def\ztmp{#1}%
\ifx\ztmp\zsomethingstupid
\expandafter\zz
\else
\expandafter
\znewcommand
\fi
#1}

\def\zz#1[#2]#3{\def#1##1{\typeout{Ignoring \string#1}}}

\usepackage{dummypackage}
\let\newcommand\znewcommand

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: A clever way ;-)

Comment: Hmm, any currently undefined command will be the same as `\somethingstupid` (before it's defined), as far as `\ifx` is concerned.

Comment: @egreg It passed all the supplied tests:-) (I'll edit)

Comment: @egreg  better..?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very fragile: what if `\newcommand*` is used? `;-)` And if the command is defined with `\def` …

Comment: that would be OK, `#1` would be `*` so it'll come back to `\znewcommand` I'm assuming the OP _knows_ the form used in the command being trapped.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In principle the form of `\newcommand` (starred/unstarred) is known to a user as long he/she looks at the package/class code. I don't see this would be an obstacle.